Apple PKPassLibrary passes() return empty response
I am encountering with the PassKit framework on iOS, specifically related to retrieving secure element passes from the Wallet after a successful push provisioning process.
Issue Summary:
In my application, I am using the remoteSecureElementPasses and passes methods from PKPassLibrary to retrieve secure element passes, such as payment cards, from the Wallet. Despite successfully adding a payment card to the Wallet via the push provisioning process, both methods consistently return an empty array, indicating that no passes are found.
Steps Taken:

Successful Push Provisioning: I have successfully added a payment card to the Wallet using the push provisioning process.
There were no errors during this process, and the card is visible
and correctly displayed in the Wallet app under the "Payment Cards"
section.

Pass Retrieval:   After confirming the card's presence in the Wallet, I attempted to retrieve it using the passes and
remoteSecureElementPasses methods. However, both methods return an
empty array, indicating that no passes are found.

Testing on Different Devices:  The issue persists across different devices, including those running iOS 13.4 and later.

Entitlements: My app's entitlements are configured correctly, and
the necessary capabilities (including Apple Pay) are enabled.

Research:  I have already searched for answers on the Apple Developer Forums, but I was unable to find a solution to this
specific issue.


Request for Assistance:
Are there any known issues or additional considerations when using passes or remoteSecureElementPasses that could lead to an empty array being returned despite the card's presence in the Wallet?
Could this issue be related to the specific configuration of the pass or some internal filtering criteria within the PKPassLibrary?
I would be grateful for any insights or recommendations you could provide to help resolve this issue.
Thank you for your time and assistance.

You need to ensure that the team and bundle id that is configured in your token provider matches the team and bundle id of your app, otherwise the passes will not be visible

@Paulw11
I've already checked that the team and bundle ID configured in my token provider matches the team and bundle ID of my app, but I'm still experiencing issues with the passes being visible.
